# Using GLEW in a static library

Tags: c++, opengl, static-libraries, glew, glfw

I have a static library project and a standard windows executable project that uses the static library. In the static library, I initialise GLEW and use various `gl*` functions in various classes (including templates). In the executable, I initialise GLFW (which happens before initialising GLEW, as required by the library) and use functions and classes defined in the static library.

However, I am getting access violations when glfwPollEvents() is called which makes me wonder if it's valid to include and initialise GLEW in a static library project used in an executable project with GLFW included and initialised.

In addition, is there anything special about static libraries in terms of memory access between the lib and exe? Is it possible to use `gl*` functions in both the static library and the executable project which alter the same context?

Comment: What is your initialisation code, up to the point of the error?

Comment: I really can't paste all my code here, there are too many classes etc. between initialisation and actually polling for events. I actually have a cloned project with no static library seperating the GLEW code from the main exe and it works perfectly, which is why my question was regarding any issues with using GLEW in a static library and not code-specific help.